# performance difference between entity_key.get() and Model.get_by_id(entity_key_id)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have 2 options to represent a related `MyData` entity from some other `MyData2` entity:

```
class MyData(ndb.Model):
    ...

class MyData2(ndb.Model):
    data_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='MyData')  # data's key
    data_key_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()        # data's key ID
```

So I have pretty much the same cost of obtaining either of `MyData`'s key or Key ID for a `MyData2` entity.

Is there any notable performance difference between accessing `MyData` by key

```
my_data = my_data2.data_key.get()
```

and accessing it by key ID?

```
my_data = MyData.get_by_id(my_data2.data_key_id)
```

I presume the access by key ID uses a built-in index lookup, but I don't know if the direct key access does a similar lookup or uses some other method to obtain the entity.

All entities are root entities, no entity group ancestry relationships are involved.

Comment: Fwiw, storing both the Key and the ID isn't necessary - anything you can do with one you can with the other, so you could save storage space by keeping just one of them.

Comment: @Greg I only have them both for this question's illustration purpose, of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ndb.Model.get_by_id` simply creates a key of the current model's Kind, and calls `get` on it, so they are for all intents and purposes identical.

Because of the async indirection, and how Model re-declares methods to deal with clashes it's not the clearest code, but you can see it [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/caac0c3e7dd4d9b2c6b32dfc5d59386dd02e6b57/ndb/model.py#L3607)